# Wav ADSPCM asset for game

Tags: gameaudio

So I exported the usual wave files straight from Pro Tools for a game, and the implementation pipeline programmer just came back and said they can't be wav, they actually have to be .adspcm   Which I guess is a form of PCM which the wav should be.

Can anyone shed any light on the situation?

Thanks guys  this one a strange one for me

Answer (score 2):

Never heard of ADSPCM, but have heard of ADPCM. If that's the one you're referring to, it's a compressed (4bit) version of PCM. It's usually used for voice in phone systems because of the low frequency range.

Good explanation here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/89879

best,

Alex

Comment: That must be it, no idea why he is saying thats the only option, surely normal music etc would sound like hell at that low quality. And how on earth would I even export to that?

Thanks again

Comment: When in doubt use audacity, the amount of times I've had to use it because it has different export options is insane. but yeah hopefully this works. 

Comment: The ONLY time I've used that format before was to screw up audio for degenerative purposes, bitcrushing, so to say. Surely that can't seriously be the only acceptable option??

Answer (score 2):

ADPCM is used quite regularly in games, although it's usually applied in-engine not on the source file.

That said its a little unusual for this form of compression to be used on all sound files.

I'd check with the programmer on what engine/toolset you're using and do a little digging yourself.

-A

Comment: Agreed, generally this is done with the engine or toolset.